# how to encode an array to base64 save it to file and then reading it and decoding it

Tags: python, base64

I would like to base64 encode some data, store it on a file, and later read it again. I wanted to use the binascii library but it seems not to do the job. Basically the method that encode to 64 also does not really return a string but a byte array. How do I get the actual base64 string?

Here below the code that show the problem

```
myArray = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]])
serializedArray = binascii.b2a_base64(myArray, newline = False)

with open("Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(str(serializedArray))

with open("Output.txt", "r") as text_file:
    readFromFile = text_file.read()

print(serializedArray)
print(readFromFile)
print(len(serializedArray))
print(len(readFromFile))
```

Comment: You can decode bytes by using .decode('utf-8')

Answer (score 0):

Reading and writing to the file using `bytes` would be much simpler to do in this case.

```
import numpy as np
import binascii

myArray = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]], dtype=np.float64)
print(myArray)
serializedArray = binascii.b2a_base64(myArray, newline = False)

with open("Output.txt", "wb") as text_file:
    text_file.write(serializedArray)

with open("Output.txt", "rb") as text_file:
    readFromFile = text_file.read()

print(type(serializedArray))
print(type(readFromFile))

print(serializedArray)
print(readFromFile)

a = binascii.a2b_base64(readFromFile)
decoded_array = np.frombuffer(a, dtype=np.float64)

print(decoded_array)
```